# Listview Results Only Show OnTextChange

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, android-edittext

My listView is attached to an editText to allow the user to search through the listView. The problem is, the data filling my listView only shows after the user enters text into the editText and I would like the results to show before the user even types anything.

```
public class Search extends Activity {

EditText editText;
ListView listview;
int textlength = 0;
int width;
Button list;
Button filter;
CustomAdapter adapter;
Location userLoc;


private ArrayList<String> brand;
private ArrayList<String> size;
private ArrayList<String> price;
private ArrayList<Integer> percent;
private ArrayList<String> objID;
private ArrayList<String> store;
private ArrayList<String> address;
private ArrayList<Integer> distance;


ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> size_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> price_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> percent_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> id_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> store_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> address_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> distance_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Integer longitude;
Integer latitude;


ParseObject dealsObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_page);

    Parse.initialize(this, "vUz23Z6zdIL1jbxbVWeLpsSdu1ClTu3YiG30zTWY",
            "4BTyoq1QQKows8qVJV7lvU3ZokSRrLFyOCPzffwJ");



    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    brand = new ArrayList<String>();
    size = new ArrayList<String>();
    price = new ArrayList<String>();
    percent = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    objID = new ArrayList<String>();
    store = new ArrayList<String>();
    address = new ArrayList<String>();
    distance = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    userLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = (int) userLoc.getLongitude();
            latitude = (int) userLoc.getLatitude();
            userLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
            userLoc.setLongitude(longitude);
        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
    getDeals();


    adapter = new CustomAdapter(brand, size, price, percent, objID, store,
            address, distance);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            textlength = editText.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            size_sort.clear();
            price_sort.clear();
            percent_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();
            id_sort.clear();
            store_sort.clear();
            address_sort.clear();
            distance_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < brand.size(); i++) {
                if (textlength <= brand.get(i).length()) {
                    if (editText
                            .getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    (String) brand.get(i).subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {

                        text_sort.add(brand.get(i));
                        size_sort.add(size.get(i));
                        price_sort.add(price.get(i));
                        percent_sort.add(percent.get(i));
                        id_sort.add(objID.get(i));
                        store_sort.add(store.get(i));
                        address_sort.add(address.get(i));
                        distance_sort.add(distance.get(i));


                        listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(text_sort,
                                size_sort, price_sort, percent_sort,
                                id_sort, store_sort, address_sort,
                                distance_sort));

                        // Register onClickListener to Handle Click Events
                        // on Each Item
                        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            //
                            // Argument position gives the index of item
                            // which is clicked
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View v, int position, long id) {

                                String brand = (String) text_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                String size = (String) size_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                String price = (String) price_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                String objID = (String) id_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                String store = (String) store_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                String address = (String) address_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                int percent = (int) percent_sort
                                        .get(position);
                                Integer distance = distance_sort
                                        .get(position);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        "com.alpha.dealtap.DEALPAGE");
                                intent.putExtra("Brand", brand);
                                intent.putExtra("Size", size);
                                intent.putExtra("Price", price);
                                intent.putExtra("Percent", percent);
                                intent.putExtra("ID", objID);
                                intent.putExtra("Store", store);
                                intent.putExtra("Address", address);
                                intent.putExtra("Distance", distance);

                                System.out.println("My Selection: "
                                        + intent.toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });

    list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);
    Button map = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);
    filter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter);

    list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(Search.this, list);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sortmenu,
                    popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if (item.getOrder() == 1) {
                        brand.clear();
                        size.clear();
                        price.clear();
                        percent.clear();
                        objID.clear();
                        store.clear();
                        address.clear();
                        distance.clear();
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        getDealsPrice();

                        System.out.println(price);

                    } else if (item.getOrder() == 2) {
                        brand.clear();
                        size.clear();
                        price.clear();
                        percent.clear();
                        objID.clear();
                        store.clear();
                        address.clear();
                        distance.clear();


                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        getDealsPercent();
                        System.out.println(price);

                    } else if (item.getOrder() == 3) {
                        brand.clear();
                        size.clear();
                        price.clear();
                        percent.clear();
                        address.clear();
                        distance.clear();


                        objID.clear();
                        store.clear();
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        getDealsName();
                        System.out.println(brand);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Shit....Item is: "
                                + item.getTitle());
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Search.this,
                            "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
        }
    });

    filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PopupMenu popupTwo = new PopupMenu(Search.this, filter);
            popupTwo.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filtermenu,
                    popupTwo.getMenu());
            popupTwo.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if (item.getOrder() == 1) {
                        brand.clear();
                        size.clear();
                        price.clear();
                        percent.clear();
                        objID.clear();
                        address.clear();
                        distance.clear();


                        store.clear();
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        getDealsName();

                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                "com.alpha.dealtap.STORESEARCH");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popupTwo.show();
        }
    });

    map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.alpha.dealtap.MAP"));

        }

    });

}

private void getDeals() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Deals");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                    brand.add(dealsObject.getString("Brand"));
                    size.add(dealsObject.getString("Size"));
                    price.add("$" + dealsObject.getString("Price"));
                    percent.add(dealsObject.getInt("Percentage"));
                    objID.add(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                    store.add(dealsObject.getString("Store"));
                    address.add(dealsObject.getString("Address"));

                    Location location = new Location("");
                    location.setLatitude(dealsObject.getInt("Latitude"));
                    location.setLongitude(dealsObject.getInt("Longitude"));

                    distance.add((int) ((userLoc.distanceTo(location))/1609.34));

                }

            } else {
                Log.v("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}

private void getDealsPrice() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Deals");
    query.addDescendingOrder("Price");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                    brand.add(dealsObject.getString("Brand"));
                    size.add(dealsObject.getString("Size"));
                    price.add("$" + dealsObject.getString("Price"));
                    percent.add(dealsObject.getInt("Percentage"));
                    objID.add(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                    store.add(dealsObject.getString("Store"));
                    address.add(dealsObject.getString("Address"));

                    Location location = new Location("");
                    location.setLatitude(dealsObject.getInt("Latitude"));
                    location.setLongitude(dealsObject.getInt("Longitude"));
                    distance.add((int) ((userLoc.distanceTo(location))/1609.34));

                }

            } else {
                Log.v("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}

private void getDealsPercent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Deals");
    query.addDescendingOrder("Percentage");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                    brand.add(dealsObject.getString("Brand"));
                    size.add(dealsObject.getString("Size"));
                    price.add("$" + dealsObject.getString("Price"));
                    percent.add(dealsObject.getInt("Percentage"));
                    objID.add(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                    store.add(dealsObject.getString("Store"));
                    address.add(dealsObject.getString("Address"));

                    Location location = new Location("");
                    location.setLatitude(dealsObject.getInt("Latitude"));
                    location.setLongitude(dealsObject.getInt("Longitude"));
                    distance.add((int) ((userLoc.distanceTo(location))/1609.34));

                }

            } else {
                Log.v("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}

private void getDealsName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Deals");
    query.addAscendingOrder("Brand");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                    brand.add(dealsObject.getString("Brand"));
                    size.add(dealsObject.getString("Size"));
                    price.add("$" + dealsObject.getString("Price"));
                    percent.add(dealsObject.getInt("Percentage"));
                    objID.add(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                    store.add(dealsObject.getString("Store"));
                    address.add(dealsObject.getString("Address"));

                    Location location = new Location("");
                    location.setLatitude(dealsObject.getInt("Latitude"));
                    location.setLongitude(dealsObject.getInt("Longitude"));
                    distance.add((int) ((userLoc.distanceTo(location))/1609.34));

                }

            } else {
                Log.v("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] data_text;
    String[] size_text;
    String[] price_text;
    String[] id_text;
    String[] store_text;
    String[] address_text;

    Integer[] percent_text;
    Integer[] distance_text;


    CustomAdapter(String[] text, String[] size, String[] price,
            Integer[] percent, String[] id, String[] store,
            String[] address, Integer[] distance) {
        data_text = text;
        size_text = size;
        price_text = price;
        percent_text = percent;
        store_text = store;
        address_text = address;
        id_text = id;
        distance_text = distance;

    }

    CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> drinkSize,
            ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<Integer> percent,
            ArrayList<String> objID, ArrayList<String> store,
            ArrayList<String> address, ArrayList<Integer> distance) {

        data_text = new String[text.size()];
        size_text = new String[drinkSize.size()];
        price_text = new String[price.size()];
        percent_text = new Integer[percent.size()];
        id_text = new String[objID.size()];
        store_text = new String[store.size()];
        address_text = new String[address.size()];
        distance_text = new Integer[distance.size()];


        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            data_text[i] = text.get(i);
            size_text[i] = drinkSize.get(i);
            price_text[i] = price.get(i);
            percent_text[i] = percent.get(i);
            id_text[i] = objID.get(i);
            store_text[i] = store.get(i);
            address_text[i] = address.get(i);
            distance_text[i] = distance.get(i);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data_text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_dropdown, parent, false);

        TextView textview = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_MainStore);
        TextView size = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_Size);
        TextView price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_Price);
        TextView percent = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_dist);
        TextView store = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.textView_Location);

        textview.setText(data_text[position]);
        size.setText(size_text[position]);
        price.setText(price_text[position]);
        percent.setText(String.valueOf(percent_text[position]) + "%");
        store.setText(store_text[position]);

        // Changes the color of the percent integer based on it's
        // number...green if higher...red if lower
        if (percent_text[position] >= 85)
            percent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        else if (percent_text[position] >= 70
                && percent_text[position] <= 85)
            percent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
        else if (percent_text[position] >= 0
                && percent_text[position] <= 70)
            percent.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        return (row);

    }
}
```

}

Sorry for the large block of code, but I've been stuck on this for a while.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

rather than

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

? This worked for me when extending ArrayAdapter, rather than BaseAdapter which I had nothing but problems with. [This tut](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/) helped immensely.